# Execute code after `UseMethod()` in generic function in R?

Tags: r, r-s3, generic-function

I would like to have the following generic function, which

1. checks for thew allowedFormats (This works),
2. than executes the generic function base on the type of argument x (works)
3. evaluates the statements after the call of `UseMethod()` (does not work - as expected)

Now it states in the help for `UseMethod`

> Any statements after the call to UseMethod will not be evaluated as UseMethod does not return.

So this is not surprising. But is there a way that I can achieve this, apart from defining an additional function `validate_after()` which calls `validate()` followed by `cat(“Validation completed”)`?

```
validate <- function (
  x,
  allowedFormats
) {

  # Check arguments ---------------------------------------------------------

  allowedFormats <- c("none", "html", "pdf", "word", "all")
  if (!(report %in% allowedFormats)) {
    stop("'report' has to be one of the following values: ", allowedFormats)
  }

  UseMethod("validate", x)

  cat(“Validation completed”)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define and call a nested generic

```
> validate <- function (x, allowedFormats) {
+     .validate <- function(x, allowedFormats) {
+         UseMethod("validate", x)
+     }
+     # Check arguments ---------------------------------------------------------
+     # ...
+     .validate(x, allowedFormats)
+     cat("Validation completed")
+ }
> validate.numeric <- function(x, allowedFormats) {
+     cat('Working...\n')
+ }
> validate(5, NA)
Working...
Validation completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you wish to achieve this might be feasible using the 'on.exit' command, as demonstrated below:

```
test <- function(x, ...){
    if(!is.integer(x))
        stop("wups")
    on.exit(cat("'On exit' executes after UseMethod, but before the value is returned. x = ", x,"\n"))
    UseMethod("test")
}
test.integer <- function(x, ...){
    cat("hello i am in a function\n")
    x <- x + 3
    cat("I am done calculating. x + 3 = ",x,"\n")
    return(x)
}
test(1:3)

hello i am in a function
I am done calculating. x + 3 =  4 5 6 
'On exit' executes after UseMethod, but before the value is returned. x =  1 2 3 
[1] 4 5 6
```

This is not necessarily a perfect solution. For example if one wished to perform some extra calculations on the methods result, the result is not propagated to the the generic function (as `UseMethod` does not return). A possible workaround could be to force feed a environment into the called method, to store results in.

Comment: Good idea. But I think for my purpose (to render a validation report afterwards), the best solution might be to use a different function.

Comment: Indeed i would suggest the same. If you were to release it as a package, it would also be simpler for others to expand upon your package, if the generic function is using common standards. Most packages validate within the method body.